# Recover files from an 11" Air?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macbook-air

My 11" Air just went belly up and is spinning indefinitely at the start up screen.

In the past, this has required a full wipe of the hard drive and fresh install of Mountain Lion.

I'm currently trying to reinstall Mountain Lion only and see if that will fix the problem but I fear that it won't, so I'm investigating my options as far as pulling the files off it.

One idea I had was to somehow enable networking and filesharing services in single-user mode so that I can simply transfer the files over the network and then do the full wipe and install, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

How should I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I happened to have a bootable USB disk from another machine lying around and I booted from that and am now rsync stuff over. I'm still interested in knowing how to turn networking services on in the event that I didn't have access to a bootable usb drive.

Comment: Could be possible there is a logical failure with the SSD. Have you run a file check on it?

Comment: Yes. All forms of disk checking check out. fsck in single user mode, disk utility permissions and disk verification in recovery mode, etc. I haven't started in Verbose Mode because I don't know how to interpret the output. This has been the symptoms on other occasions like this. I'm even more nervous this time though because firmware got installed moments before the machine failed to boot.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to get another Macbook - boot the old 11" Air into the data transfer mode by holding the T key:

the computer is off, start it up while holding down the T key.

Boot the 2nd airbook up and connect it to the original via Thunderbolt or FireWire cable

It will show the original MacBook as a drive so you can copy the files from it

More info:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725

Please note - the firewire reference above was made to Macbooks PRO as obviously the Air doesn't have that port. I wrote the answer to be more generic so any Mac users could follow it...

Comment: Ah, I had missed in all my excitement that Apple had added support for Target Disk Mode to thunderbolt. I don't have a thunderbolt cable but if I did this one would surely take the cake, especially given the transfer speeds I could see.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Thunderbolt - FireWire will work as well and the data transfer speeds are much better.

Comment: FireWire on an 11" air?

Comment: Happy to accept this answer if you can mention that FireWire is not supported on Macbook Airs